# The angularjs dialog doesn't seem to work for me

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dialog, angularjs-material

I have been trying to implement AngularJS dialog in my app and i copy everything from the demos provided in [material.angularjs.org](http://material.angularjs.org) however I don't seem to be able to make it work. Could anyone see what am I missing ?

This is the Javascript code:

```
  // TABLE CONTROLLS GO HERE 
app.controller('AddTableController',['$scope', function($scope,$mdDialog){
        $scope.allTables = tables;
        //method to add tables 
        $scope.showAdvanced= function(ev) {
            $mdDialog.show({
              controller:DialogController,
              templateUrl:'index_directives/dialog-add-table.html',
            })
        };
}]);
//HELPER METHOD FOR THE AddTableController//////////////////////////////
function DialogController($scope, $mdDialog) {
  $scope.hide = function() {
    $mdDialog.hide();
  };
  $scope.cancel = function() {
    $mdDialog.cancel();
  };
  $scope.answer = function(answer) {
    $mdDialog.hide(answer);
  };
}
```

Then the function is called on button click :

```
<md-button class="md-fab add-button" ng-click="showAlert($event)">+</md-button>
```

From the error log in the console I get something like this:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of undefined
    at n.app.controller.$scope.showAlert (http://localhost/angular/js/app.js:24:16)
    at ib.functionCall (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:199:303)
    at Ec.(anonymous function).compile.d.on.f (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:216:74)
    at n.$get.n.$eval (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:126:15)
    at n.$get.n.$apply (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:126:241)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to define the $mdDialog dependency:

```
app.controller('AddTableController',['$scope', '$mdDialog', function($scope,$mdDialog){
```

Since it's very common forgetting to define the dependency injection, you may be interested on [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29868888/why-wouldnt-you-use-explicit-annotations-when-defining-controllers-in-angularjs/29873484#29873484) of @Michael Benford regarding ng-annotate.

Comment: Thank you Daniel, for some odd reasons I had added the dependency in an other controller without realizing it. Thanks !

Comment: You're welcome @KushtrimAbdiu. Please note that I've made an amendment on the answer.